# Embed Youtube Video into Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube

When I put

```
<iframe width="560" height="349" src="<%= @video.link %>"></iframe>
```

Everything shows up fine. But the actual video won't play.. what am I doing wrong?

```
<iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://youtu.be/PF9-lstnLvo">
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 </iframe>
```

HELP!!

Answer (score 6):

Wrong src at iframe, it need to be like:

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/PF9-lstnLvo`

You need to add code:string to you Video model.

Or method code, which return you this code from @video.link like this:

```
def code
  self.link.split('/').last if self.link
end
```

And replace erb:

`<iframe width="560" height="349" src="<%= "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+@video.code %>"></iframe>`